# Wordpress CMB2 show-on page template - default page template

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I am using CMB2 and would like to only show a particular CMb2 metabox on the default page template. I have tried passing a value of page.php as the value of the show-on filter but its not working. Any ideas welcome? I could write my own custom show-on filter but I am sure the functionality must already exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while, so maybe you've found the answer. But since I've been looking myself as well, let me post the result here for future reference.

The solution is simply, instead of 'page.php', just use 'default' as the value for the show-on filter:

`'show_on' => array( 'key' => 'page-template', 'value' => 'default' )`

Answer (score 0):

@ruude3 answer works. Also you'll need to either save the new page as a draft or publish it before the meta fields will appear.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30813035)